# react: what happend if I import a component which import a higher version react in a lower version react project

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

react: what happend if I import a component which import a higher version react in a lower version react project.
Does there will has two diff version of react in diff module? or just has one react?
Does there any diff between webpack and native es6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one version of react if defined as [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/). Of course you should only use features supported by both versions.

Comment: What if I do not definded the  peer dependency?

Comment: Two versions of react